# jquery selector which finds an element which has an attribute with one of several values

Tags: jquery

I need a jquery ninja to help me find the best jquery selector to solve my need:

```
// pseudo jquery selector:
var match = $('table[facet=ProductCateogory or ProductCatagoryTier2 or DocumentCategory]')


// this would not match:
<table facet="EiaBrand"

// this would match:
<table facet="ProductCategory"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to specify them separately using the [*multiple selector `,`*](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
var match = $('table[facet=ProductCateogory],table[facet=ProductCatagoryTier2],table[facet=DocumentCategory]')
```

Comment: This is not quite working. (note the "a" at the end) do i need parenthesis?. $('table[facet=EiaProductCategoryTier2],table[facet=ProductCategory],table[facet=DocumentCategory] a.FacetItems');

Comment: @BrokeMyLegBiking: Do you want to find `a.FacetItems` in all tables? Then you have to do: `$('table[facet=EiaProductCategoryTier2],table...,table...').find('a.FacetItems')`... or you have to add `a...` after each `tabel...` otherwise it will only apply to the last one.